# word is autosaving document on every key stroke

Tags: microsoft-word, paging, autosave

For some reason word has started saving my document each time that I type a keystroke.  I have set autosave to 10 minutes, but it does not make a difference.
Thanks in advance
S

Comment: may help if you include a screenshot over where you set it to autosave every 10min

Comment: Are there any add-ons in Word?

Comment: Which version of word? In office 365 it might indeed save every modification. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-autosave-11c9f922-020b-439f-97f7-09b0041ed7cd

Comment: In *File menu > Options > Save", section "Save documents", what is the value of "Save AutoRecover information every ..."?

Comment: Have you newly installed antivirus software? As far as I know, some anti-virus software also has a file saving mechanism. When you edit a document, it will also call the save function. Please check the relevant settings